# What would be good example of antisymmetry for this relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

We have set

$X=\{a,b,c,d\}$

and relation

$R=\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(b,b),(c,c),(d,b),(d,c),(d,d)\}$.

It is obvious that it is not symmetric and I suppose that it is antisymmetric but I can't come up with some good example to show it.

I know the rule of antisymmetry $xRy \wedge yRx \rightarrow x = y$, but I am not sure how to apply it on this relation.

Comment: Just have to check cases.  We have $aRb$ but not $bRa$, we have $aRc$ but not $cRa$ and so on.

Comment: That would be proof for symmetry, that this relation is not symmetric.

Comment: No...you have to check each such case to confirm antisymmetry.  No one example will do the job.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood you. What are you saying is that I need to check same cases as for symmetry?

Comment: Exactly.  With symmetry you have to check each $xRy$ to confirm that $yRx$.  With anti-symmetry you have to check each case $xRy$ to confirm that you do not have $yRx$.

Comment: That makes sense, but now I am not sure about rule of antisymmetry. Why it says $xRy \wedge yRx \rightarrow x = y$. Why $x = y$?

Comment: The definition means "there are no non-reflexive examples of symmetry".  Thus for $x\neq y$ you can't have both $xRy$ and $yRx$.  You can have one or the other or neither but you can't have both.

Comment: @ZvnokyBrown That to make sure that it is not symmetric! It says *if it happens that* xRy and yRx then it must be that x = y. x and y distinct will mean it is symmetric!

Comment: Oh okay, now it is everything clear. Thank you lulu and samjoe.

Answer (score 1):

A single example will not suffice.   You are required to affirm that a counterexample does not exist.

The relation $\rm R$ will *not* be antisymmetric if you can find any $x,y$ such that $x\neq y$, $x\operatorname{R} y$, *and* $y\operatorname{R} x$.   Only if you can be definite that there is *no* such pair can you assert antisymmetry.

This requires an exhaustive check of the elements of $\rm R$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't “give an example” for antisimmetry. You could give an example for failure of antisymmetry.

How can you show this is antisymmetric? Let's stretch it a bit and suppose we have also proved it is transitive. Then it should be an order relation and the pairs tell us that

- $a$ precedes $b$
- $a$ precedes $c$
- $a$ precedes $d$
- $d$ precedes $b$
- $d$ precedes $c$

and no other relation between distinct elements holds. Now we can see that all pairs necessary for the order relation above are indeed present. So the relation $R$ is indeed antisymmetric *and* transitive.

This is the Hasse diagram for the relation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to exhaustively check through most of $R$. The following algorithm will allow you to determine if it is antisymmetric or not.

---

isAntisymmetric $\leftarrow$ True

for each $(x,y) \in R$:

$\quad$ if $x<y$:

$\quad\quad$ if $(y,x) \in R$: //use that $R$ (in this case) is lexographically ordered to quickly determine this

$\quad\quad\quad$ isAntisymmetric $\leftarrow$ False

return isAntisymmetric